# PHP Pear Package - Pager on Awardspace Hosting Question?

Tags: php, package, pear, pager

I am using awardspace.com for free website hosting. Does anyone know how to change the include path such that I can use the PEAR `pager.php` package?

Currently my script has:

```
include_once 'pager/Pager.php';
```

While the include path on Unix server on awardspace says:

```
include_path .:/usr/local/php5/share/pear
```

Answer (score 0):

[`set_include_path()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) should work.

To append another path to the existing one:

```
<?php
$path = '/path/to/mydir';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
```

Comment: I dont actually want to chnage the path and found out that its working only the PHP pager (sliding or Jumping) functionality is not working. Cna you give a light on that. Thanks
Anita

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked or worked your way through the documentation at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.html.pager.php ?
What seems to be the actual problem? Being a little less vague would help!

Comment: Its working now...althought the server does not have pager installed...i took files under Pager directory on my localhost/homeserver and posted them on awardspace base folder (home/root dir of mine). And now voila it all works fine. A Temporary but working solution. Anita